# Get mysql to block all new connections but honor existing ones in preparation for being taken out of service

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm looking for a way to get MySQL (actually MariaDB) to block all new connections but honor existing ones. I'd intend to put this restriction in place before taking the server down for maintenance. I envisage the process as follows:

1. Block new connections
2. Wait until existing connections have all finished
3. Have a way of checking that they are all finished
4. Take server down
5. Perform maintenance
6. Bring server back up

I'm thinking that possibly it could be done with `max_connections` but I'd still need to be able to connect to determine that all processes had finished. Or can you change the IPs that the server will listen on without a restart? Or maybe it could be done by blocking the user, but this is cluster replicated with Galera so I'd only want this to affect a single node.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are the connections being made ?

Comment: Sorry, currently they are being made by php's `mysqli` though an HAProxy load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to change take the IP from the loadbalancer - the state full connections will complete and the new ones will be just redirected to the other MySQL server . When you can not see any more connections on the MySQl server that must be maintained , change the IP , restart the server , add the server back to the HA . Please check this as this solution really depends on the environment

Comment: Yes, this is a better plan and should work well. Thanks.